# Angular Testing Errors with Karma

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'am having an issue starting my angular project testing.

Context:

I have one main component that nest other component to show a spinner just like this:

```
<div class='showSpinner' *ngIf="showSpinnerCustomer">
    <div class="spinner">
      <app-spinnerCustomers></app-spinnerCustomers>
      <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

The problem comes when I start the command ng test and appear this type of error:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'app-spinnerCustomers' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-spinnerCustomers' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-spinnerCustomers' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  <div class='showSpinner' *ngIf="showSpinnerCustomer">
    <div class="spinner">
      [ERROR ->]<app-spinnerCustomers></app-spinnerCustomers>
      <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/ListCustomersComponent.html@12:6
```

I have this modularized in 2 modules:

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTES } from './app.routes';
import { ListCustomersComponent } from './components/list-customers/list-customers.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomerService } from './services/customer/customer.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SpinnersModule } from './components/spinners/spinners.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListCustomersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    APP_ROUTES,
    SpinnersModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CustomerService
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in the spinner module:

**spinners.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SpinnerCustomersComponent } from './spinnerCustomers/spinnerCustomers.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SpinnerCustomersComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [
        SpinnerCustomersComponent
    ]
  })
export class SpinnersModule { }
```

Any clue what is going on here and what could I do to fix it? 
I have run out of ideas.

Thank you.

> EDIT:
>   app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
  it(`should have as title 'app'`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app');
  }));
});
```

> spinnerCustonmers.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SpinnerCustomersComponent } from './spinnerCustomers.component';

describe('SpinnerCustomersComponent', () => {
  let component: SpinnerCustomersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SpinnerCustomersComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SpinnerCustomersComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SpinnerCustomersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: hi, add app-spinnerCustomers to declarations in your module

Comment: Can you show the module from your TestBed?

Comment: Hi @Zircon, i have edit the question, thank you for take your time!

Comment: @Arm144, please try adding your `SpinnersModule` to the imports of your `AppComponent`'s spec module.

Comment: @Zircon Still having the problem `import { SpinnersModule } from './components/spinners/spinners.module';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        SpinnersModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  })); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correction adding de SpinnerModule inside each component spec.ts file

```
import { SpinnersModule } from '../spinners/spinners.module';

describe('ListCustomersComponent', () => {
  let component: ListCustomersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListCustomersComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SpinnersModule],
      declarations: [ ListCustomersComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Thank you all!!